# Is there any API for changing a user's password in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm struggling with whether it's possible to create an utility to manage password resets for our Hybris Commerce Suite (version 5.1.0). Is there any known API that would allow me to programmatically modify the password of an existing user's account without having to do it manually using the HMC?

For example:

- A REST API?
- Or running impex code from the command line? (this seems to have been introduced in version 5.5)
- A Java API?
- Change it directly on the database?
- Anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look on CustomersController in ycommercewebservices extension. also we can  change the password using impexfile.

Or check out the REST service: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/ycommercewebservices+Extension

Comment: Thanks i will check. I know about impex, but as far as i know, versions previous to 5.5 only ran impex via the Web interface (manually).

Comment: you can run impex from HAC

Comment: yes,sorry I miss read your last update.still you can have a look on hybris OOTB webservices which has customer rest service calls

Comment: Hello, sree, do you know where is the documentation for these REST services?

Comment: Hybris documentation is like a maze of twisty little passages all alike. I feel the functionality to edit customer records exists, but every time i get close to it, the piece i need is not there.

Comment: have you seen changeCustomerPassword function in CustomersController class. this will take care of changing the customer password

Answer (score 0):

Also you if want some sort of custom logic around the Customer, you can extend de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.customer.CustomerFacade . There are methods for password handling.

Answer (score 0):

type- PUT,POST

v1 -/{site}/customers/current/password
v2 -/{site}/users/{userId}/password

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?title=OCC+Sample+Flows&spaceKey=release5#OCCSampleFlows-ManageCustomerProfile

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?title=Migrating+to+OCC+v2&spaceKey=release5

**Parameters Required:**

access_token - Access Token,  old – Old Password,  new – New Password

**Response**

Http 202 – Accepted